# Can't access HDD due to partitioning problems

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart

So I have a HDD full of my media, photos music etc. It was working fine in windows 10, but since reverting back to windows 8 (os is on an SSD) I can no longer find the drive in my computer. I've checked hundreds of posts, and here's what I have:

diskpart shows the disk. it shows 2 partitons, both have no volumes attached. When I list volumes, it shows those for other disks:
[image]

disk management shows it as a storage pool, but when I right click, all options are greyed out:
[image]

partition wizard doesn't even show the drive:
[image]

FindAndMount wont even show any partitions:
[image]

Can you please advise on how I can get this seemingly healthy partition to show up in My Computer. I know I have an option to try 'clean' in DiskPart but it's really important that I recover the files on the drive so that really is a last resort.

Edit: Just to add to this, I never intentionally created a storage pool so I'm not sure why windows decided that this HDD should be one.

Comment: Can you reinstall Windows 10 and check if you have access to your data ? Or put your drive in another PC with Windows 10 ?

Comment: I've connected it to a windows 7 PC that shows the same thing. I'll try downloading and reinstalling 10 but I have a feeling it'll do the same

Comment: Windows storage pool are kind of buggy. I hope using the same OS version that played with the storage pool will do the trick.

Comment: Did you perhaps use EFS with your storage pool? What does `Storage Spaces` in control panel show?

Comment: @ssnobody I don't know what EFS is. I never actually selected to create a storage space. I'll grab a screenshot when i'm home, but it shows the drive and says it needs to be 'reset' but i'm concerned that it'll do the same as if I do a clean in diskpart, and format it.

Comment: If you are saying, I accidentally repartitioned a disk as storage pool and now I'd like to undo that and try to recover my data it's a bit of a different question. It does appear it's a storage pool now, and since that's a non-standard partition ID, most tools won't know what to do with it. You might try `testdisk`

Comment: The problem which you forgot to mention in your question is that the drive is not partitioned at all, it is using **storage spaces**. Like other logical volume managers, you cannot directly access the underlying partitions. They are only there to stop you accidentally deleting the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still can't explain the odd functionality experienced when using this HDD in Windows 8 or 7, but since installing Windows 10 again, the HDD shows up fine. (Thanks mallok) All I can imagine is Win 10 does something to identify the fact that it's a storage drive rather than a OS drive and gives it some identifier that Windows 8 sees as a storage pool. The other factor may be that I called the drive "Storage" - as that's where I stored my media.

The fact is, having installed Windows 10, it seems to have fixed the problem.

Now to buy a NAS for backups...